# ASP.NET Core set timezone on a per user basis?

Tags: asp.net, date, datetime, asp.net-core

I have a web application that is used globally.

All dates and times are stored as UTC and currently displayed as UTC with a small footer stating "All times and dates are displayed in UTC".

Obviously, most people do not know nor care about UTC, so instead I'm looking to call `someDate.ToLocalTime()` - which works well when the user's system is set to the local country and the browser passes that info through.

However, sometimes / often the users system is set to USA or some other default and displays the wrong time. In this instance, I can display a list of timezones available, for example:

```
<form id="selectTimezone" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="SetTimezone" asp-route-returnUrl="@Context.Request.Path" asp-area="" method="post" role="form">
    <div class="form-group form-group-sm">
        <label class="control-label">@Localiser["Timezone:"]</label>
        <select name="timezoneId" class="form-control" asp-for="@TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id">
            @foreach (var timeZone in TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones())
            {
                <option value="@(timeZone.Id)">@timeZone.DisplayName (@timeZone.StandardName)</option>
            }
        </select>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-bottom: 0px;">@SharedLocaliser["Set Language"]</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

My question is, and I can't find it - can I set a session wide default timezone at all?

Or will I need to store it against the user's account, then read it into a cookie and process it by adding the required number of seconds to UTC each time?

Something like:

```
TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(someDate, myTimeZoneId);
```

Comment: The best approach I can think of, is to have a "timezone" claim. When the user logs in, you pull this claim. For unauthenticated users you can go with a default claim or fallback to one of the other strategies.

Comment: Session or claim (doesn't claim hit the db every time it's requested?), it still doesn't set the session timezone for `toLocalTime()` right? So we'd still need to pass the value through `Timezone info.convert()` right?

Answer (score 0):

Storing all datetime data in UTC and keeping a TimeZoneId for each user in the user DB then converting UTC against the preferred (user-intended) timezone should work fine in most cases. Option for the user to change this TimeZoneId as part of user preferences will help the user change it when needed. If you want to go one step further, store a column for Timezone rule changes as well and write rule update routines for those cases alone. These articles by [Dino Esposito](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/development/dotnet-development/abstracting-system-time-asp-net-applications/) and [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/) have more meat to dwell.

On .NET core, these two articles - [Cross-platform Time Zones with .NET Core](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/cross-platform-time-zones-with-net-core/) and Matt's latest blog [Date, Time, and Time Zone Enhancements in .NET 6](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/date-time-and-time-zone-enhancements-in-net-6/) will help decide your strategy. If your application is really into precision and versatile Date, Time and Timezone based presentation, then get your hands dirty with [Noda Time](https://nodatime.org/).